# maven build - version information

Tags: java, maven

We specify versionId in POM and correspondingly maven produces foo-version.jar. Example: foo-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar.

Is it possible to do do the following with maven?

- Not specify versionId in POM but specify build version from command line. This will help not "hardcode" the version in POM and changing it for each release, but specify it through a super build script.

Comment: Changing for release should be done by release plugin and not manually.

Comment: When you have a specific binary version of your software, how will you know which version of the source was used to build it?

Answer (score 5):

Set project version in pom as a place holder

```
<groupId>test</groupId>
<artifactId>x</artifactId>
<version>${project.version}</version>
```

now you can pass version from command line

```
mvn -Dproject.version=1.1.1 package
```

Comment: I tried that in old days of Maven 2, iirc this approach is not working. The resulting POM is generated unusable.  (I wish this have been improved now).  That's the reason why I need to write a little script to do the version change of POMs

Comment: This worked but the generated/installed POM also has `<version>${project.version}</version>`. Won't this be a problem for a depending module to use this module? Preferrebly, the generated POM should have actual version that the module is built for.

Answer (score 4):

You could use the [maven release plugin](http://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/index.html).

`release:update-versions -DautoVersionSubmodules=true`

you need autoVersionSubmodules if you want the same version for each module. Else you will need to specify version for each.

This will only increment your current version, if you want a specific version add `-DdevelopmentVersion=your version` to your command

**UPDATE**
I found another plugin that does the trick. [The maven versions plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/)

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
  <artifactId>versions-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.1</version>
</plugin>
```

With this command you can set the version:
`versions:set -DnewVersion=your version`

Comment: When I tried the first option, I got this error: `[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.3.2:update-versions (default-cli) on project simple: Missing required setting: scm connection or developerConnection must be specified. -> [Help 1]`. The second option updated the version *after* the build! In any case, the idea is to keep the version out of POM as POM is checked into CM and we do not want to commit the file for each build.

Comment: then you need to add the scm tag to your pom, [here's](http://maven.apache.org/scm/maven-scm-plugin/usage.html) an example of it's usage